# How to create custom Notification contain some controls

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to create a custom notification for my music app. I found that we can use Remote view to custom layout of notification. But it can't be used to implement some events like `onClick` on a button...

I found my default Music app in my Android have a great notification.(Android 2.3.6)

Answer (score 0):

sure you can use clicks on RemoteViews but has a different flavour your

```
 onUpdate
```

will have something this

```
//To goto class
Intent intent = new Intent(context, "Your class".class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
          remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update_class, pendingIntent);

          appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
//To goto Service
          Intent it = new Intent();
          it.setClass(context, "Your Service".class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getService(context,
          0,
          it, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.service_controller,
                pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
```

you will have to use **remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent("id of button/textview","corresponding peinding intent")**

Comment: May be just system app can do like that. Anyway, thanks for your anwser, Vincent :)