# Android Push Notification as an invite

Tags: android, push-notification

I want from my Java server to be able to send an Android notification that will take the form of an invite. I'm currently able to send a basic Android notification, but I want to appear on the screen in form of an invite with options like 'Yes, I accept' or 'No, I refuse' and then send the answer back to the sender. How would you do something like this? I have no clue how should I do it and I can't find anything on the Internet.
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you receive a pushed message from server, you can launch a new Activity which has a dialog style, then you can do your business in that activity.

the case is very much the same as receiving a sms.

Comment: It would be better to pass an Intent with desired activity to the Android notification.

Comment: @PozzoApps yeah, it is also fine. But it seems that Alex wants to show it up directly.

Comment: OK, I think I get it. I have to read about switching between activities since now I am using only one main Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom layout for your notification using `RemoteViews` and manage OnClick events. See [Android Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), and this question might help you too [Create Notification using some controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344649/how-to-create-custom-notification-contain-some-controls)